# How to install pyYAML on windows 10

Tags: python, windows, pyyaml

Im trying to install pyYAML from source on windows 10. I downloaded PyYAML 3.11 from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyYAML. When I run setup.py I get error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified. How to fix it?

```
PyYAML-3.11>python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\yaml
copying lib3\yaml\composer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\yaml
copying lib3\yaml\constructor.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\yaml
copying lib3\yaml\cyaml.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\yaml
copying lib3\yaml\dumper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\yaml
copying lib3\yaml\emitter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\yaml
copying lib3\yaml\error.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\yaml
copying lib3\yaml\events.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\yaml
copying lib3\yaml\loader.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\yaml
copying lib3\yaml\nodes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\yaml
copying lib3\yaml\parser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\yaml
copying lib3\yaml\reader.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\yaml
copying lib3\yaml\representer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\yaml
copying lib3\yaml\resolver.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\yaml
copying lib3\yaml\scanner.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\yaml
copying lib3\yaml\serializer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\yaml
copying lib3\yaml\tokens.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\yaml
copying lib3\yaml\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\yaml
running build_ext
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release
checking if libyaml is compilable
error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Download the wheel from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyyaml that suits your need (Python version, 32/64 bit).
2. `$ pip3 install PyYAML-3.11-cp35-none-win32.whl`

Comment: I am on win64 but I don't see any `win64` option. I tried `win_amd64` option but I get error `ERROR: PyYAML-5.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

Answer (score 3):

just run:

```
pip install PyYAML==5.3.1
```

in powershell

Comment: I did not expect that one to work... but it did

Answer (score 2):

I install PyYAML following these steps:

1. clone or download https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml
2. open cmd and `cd` to the downloaded path
3. execute `python setup.py install` as README in the repo says

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install many dependencies to get a proper build environment setup in Windows.

To make your life easy, there are use the windows installers (the .exe files) that correspond to your version of **Python** (so if you have installed 32 bit Python on 64bit Windows, use the 32bit installers).

The installers are listed on the [PyPi index page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyYAML) for PyYAML.

The only drawback is that these installers will not work correct in a virtual environment, so you'll have to install them against the base version of Python.

Comment: I tried that... says python version 3.4 required which was not found in yur registry. I am running python 3.5

Comment: Python 3.5 is not supported; you can see that builds are provided for Python 3.4, and officially only 3.2 is listed as compatible.

Comment: so ill have to downgrade my python? is there any other way ?

Comment: I'm afraid not, as even if you were to compile and build it against 3.5; as it is not officially supported with Python 3.5; you may have issues. You can check the [official wiki](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAML) for updates on when Python 3.5 will be supported.

Comment: You can find pyYAML binaries for Python 3.5 at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyyaml. All tests pass.

Answer (score 0):

Download suitable(Python version, 32/64 bit) .exe file from http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAML, then double click it to install PyYAML to your Windows 10 PC following the wizard window.

Comment: Please be specific to question

Comment: Just double click the .exe file, and flow the guide window, very simple.